# Turn based multiplayer game on iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, multiplayer

I have created an app, which I am now looking to apply turn based multiplayer to. Just to be clear, I do not have much server experience at all. I do know a bit about mySql, though.

Do anyone of you have a sense of how this is achieved? I am looking for a solution that works the same way as Draw Something and Words With Friends.

**Do they just use a web- service and a database to store each game session?**

I have looked into Amazon Web Services, and it seems they have quite a lot of what I am looking for in their iOS SDK, but I don't know if it will be too expensive.

I have searched through quite a bit of the "out of the box" solutions, such as photon and smartfox, but they both seems like overkill for someone who wants JUST turn based multiplayer.

Any help would be appreciated, and I will edit this post with the information I find :)

Cheers,
Olav

Comment: I think a webservice with a database for state information sounds like a good approach.

Comment: Yes, I've been reading around a bit, and it looks like the way to go is iPhone > web- service > couchDB. Again, I'm not an expert of any sorts on web- services, or database management, so I'm yet to find out how I'm going to set it up :) I will update if I find any more information on the subject

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question the right way, but if you don't know much about server-side computing and want out-of-the-box TurnBased Match handling you should probably look into Apple's official turn-based match GameCenter Framework.

See the official documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKTurnBasedMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010894-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)
And a very good [tutorial from Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12)

Also OpenFeint has an [API for turn-based match handling](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/openfeint-api-for-ios-turn-based-multiplayer-implementation-guide/)

These solutions will never give you the same control you would get with your own server, but it seems it could fit your needs.

Good luck with you project